# How does the Swift AppDelegate Know What View to Show?

Tags: swift, xcode

I am new to Xcode and Swift GUI programing.
When I start a new project in Xcode (MacOs Game project) it creates a starting Hello World program. The default AppDelgate.swift code is shown below. And it works when I run it and displays "Hello World". I understand that this code acts as the "main" starting point for the code execution, even though I could not find official documentation for the @NSApplicationMain Attribute.

My question is, how does this code know to display the view in the ViewController.swift file? The AppDelegate.swift code is basically empty, with no real code. How does it know what ViewController to display? How does it know to do anything at all?

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
    }
    
    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose your project file from the `Project navigator` and you'll be able to see the `Main Interface` value set as `Main` which means `Main.storyboard` file will be used as main interfase. You can remove that and you'll find the app no longer shows the view controller.

[image: Project Navigator]

You can remove the `Main Interface` provided in the `Project Navigator` and override the `contentViewController` from `AppDelegate` on a Cocoa application like this.

```
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    var window: NSWindow?

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        window = NSWindow(contentViewController: ViewController())
        window?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the extra information on how to explicitly invoke a window using (Swift) source code.

Answer (score 1):

This is determined via `Info.plist`. Check your target's settings, and you will find an entry called "Main Interface" which points to a storyboard or nib file.